# MySql Result Set Combine Columns

Tags: mysql, resultset

I have this result set from my query:

```
OrderId CustomerId  ProducerId  CustomerPayment ProducerPayment
1       1           3           10              5
1       1           4           10              5
1       2           3           10              5
1       2           4           10              5
```

I need to return this result into this:

```
OrderId UserId  Payment
1       1       20
1       2       20
1       3       10
1       4       10
```

Just combining the `CustomerId` and `ProducerId` into `UserId`. Same with the `Payment` Columns.

Is there any way to achieve this with using just a simple `select` and `group by`? I'm avoiding `temp tables`, calling multiple same `queries` and like for optimization. I hope this is possible.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you would need to normalise your data in order to achieve what you are looking for. break the customer, customerpayment as one record, and the producerid and producerpayment as another record

Comment: Thanks, but how can I break them? The first table is already a result from a query. Just need to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
OrderId,
CustomerID AS UserId,
SUM (CustomerPayment) As Payment
FROM orders
UNION ALL
SELECT 
OrderId,
ProducerId AS UserId,
SUM (ProducerPayment) As Payment
FROM orders
```

Comment: So there is no other way but this? I'm thinking if I can just call the `orders` from your query only once. Following your answer will yield to calling same query twice. Thanks BTW

Comment: Didn't you forget the group by clause?

Comment: I guess this is the only way. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select
    OrderId,
    CustomerId,
    sum(CustomerPayment) Payment,
    group_concat(OrderId separator ',') listOrders /* list all OrderID's from the user and separates these with a , */
from your_table
group by CustomerId
```

Dont know how you query looks like atm?